# Parse server : Adding Search filter to a Parse ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-server, android-search

I'm trying to add a search ListView with Parse api. But I could not add can anyone tell me how to add it ? (It is a typical ListView just fetching some text from parse).

Comment: Parse is shutting down why are you using parse

Comment: Hi, I'm using a parse server not from parse.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957337/parse-com-how-to-adding-a-search-filter-for-a-parse-listview-inside-inside-a-f  this is my code @Abhishek Singh

Answer (score 0):

Try the parse query adapter. It's an easy adapter for getting parse queries into a list.

If you want to filter a query you have already pulled from the server then you could save all the results to the local datastore and then query that to save the amount of downloads required.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/wiki/ParseQueryAdapter